# Error creating row on form

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

After I try to create a new row in one of my pages on APEX, the following error appears:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BD43015.SYS_C001194280) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "BD43015.INSERT_STUDENT", line 4 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'BD43015.INSERT_STUDENT' ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL", line 549 ORA-06512: at "APEX_040000.WWV_FLOW_DML", line 1121 ORA-22816: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause
>       Error    Unable to process row of table V_ALLSTUDENTS.
>   OK

NOTE: I'm trying to use this trigger:

```
create or replace trigger insert_student
instead of insert on v_allstudents
for each row
begin
  insert into members values(:new.memberID, :new.name, :new.birth, :new.regist_date, :new.address, :new.sex, :new.phone);
  insert into students values(:new.memberID, :new.guardian, :new.rank, :new.plan_name, :new.plan_value);
end;
/
```

And this view:

```
create or replace view v_allstudents(memberID, name, birth, regist_date, address, sex, phone, guardian, rank, plan_name, plan_value) AS
select members.memberID, name, birth, regist_date, address, sex, phone, guardian, rank, plan_name, plan_value
from members, students
where members.memberID = students.memberID
order by members.name;
```

Table members:

```
drop table members cascade constraints;
create table members(
  memberID number(10) not null,
  name varchar2(30) not null,
  birth date not null,
  regist_date date not null,
  address varchar2(50) not null,
  sex char(1) not null CHECK (sex IN ('F', 'M')),
  phone number(9),
  primary key(memberID)
);
```

Table Students:

```
drop table students cascade constraints;
create table students(
  memberID number(10) not null,
  guardian varchar2(30),
  rank varchar2(20) not null,
  plan_name varchar2 (30) not null,
  plan_value number(10) not null,
  primary key(memberID),
  foreign key(memberID) references members(memberID)
);
```

EDIT FIX: We had a trigger in conflict with the insertion of the `memberID`.

Comment: Please post the table structure for the members and students tables along with all the constraints. Also, can you try inserting a row in the v_allstudents from SQLPLUS or SQL Developer. Doing this will help you understand if the problem is with Oracle Apex or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could successfully reproduce the issue from SQLPLUS.

The following statement works.

```
declare
  v_memberid number;
begin
  insert into 
  v_allstudents(memberID, name, birth, regist_date, address, sex, phone, guardian, rank, plan_name, plan_value)
  values
  (1,'Neo',to_date('13-Jan-2009','dd-mon-yyyy'),to_date('13-Jan-2009','dd-mon-yyyy'),'My address','M',1234,'Trinity',1,'My Plan',2525)
end;
```

The following statement does not work and throws ORA-22816.

```
declare
  v_memberid number;
begin
  insert into 
  v_allstudents(memberID, name, birth, regist_date, address, sex, phone, guardian, rank, plan_name, plan_value)
values
  (1,'Neo',to_date('13-Jan-2009','dd-mon-yyyy'),to_date('13-Jan-2009','dd-mon-yyyy'),'My address','M',1234,'Trinity',1,'My Plan',2525)
  returning memberID into v_memberid;
end;
```

Here is the description for the error from Oracle documentation.

RETURNING clause is currently not supported for object type columns, LONG columns, remote tables, INSERT with subquery, **and INSTEAD OF Triggers**.

In this case either Oracle Apex is generating an Insert statement with the returning clause or you have written bespoke code in Oracle Apex with a returning clause.

I would recommend doing away with instead of trigger and inserting values into both these tables using Oracle apex forms.