# Interactive Grid with ediable view (INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON ) causing ORA-22816

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid using an editable view (INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE  ON ) on Oracle APEX Application Express 19.2.0.00.18 however I'm getting the following error:

ORA-22816: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause

Any ideas?

I read here [Error creating row on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381901/error-creating-row-on-form) that it's not supported by Oracle but I'm hoping since that post was from 4 years ago, things have changed.

Comment: Can you give more details? Based on the error probably you are trying to use RETURNING clause into a column, but we need to see what you are trying to do there. Also, what you mean saying "INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON"?

Comment: Sure @HigorPereira, I'm upgrading a tabular form to an interactive grid. So generally in an IG you have 1 table that is editable but in my case I have a view. So when a user tries to insert ,update, delete on that view, it calls a trigger in the backend that will do a bunch of things in case of an insert, update or delete kind of like this https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-instead-of-triggers/

Comment: Try changing your primary key to the ROWID column. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Nevermind, I just created a test and got the same error. Here's what I recommend you do. Move the logic from your instead of trigger into a package and update the trigger to invoke the package. That will allow the old logic to continue working as before. Next, change your IG to use custom PL/SQL processing and invoke the stored procedure. Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGhan.....I'll try that....sounds like it might work. This is what I get for customizing the process with tabular forms so much!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles upon this, the error happens because of the "Automatic Row Processing" APEX does for Interactie Grid where it tries to get a primary key of the inserted record.

It can be disabled like this:

- Open Page Designer for your page with the Interactive Grid
- At the top of the left side menu open click the icon with two arrows forming a rectangle (looks kinda like a typical "reload" button) to open the "Process Tree"
- Select "Processing" - "Processes" - "[Your page name] - Save Interactive Grid Data"
- In the right side menu disable the "Settings" - "Return Primary Key(s) after Insert" toggle

After that the error should disappear, but your Interactive Grid won't automatically update after insertion.

You can make APEX reload the grid or the whole page after changes are saved into the Interactive Grid as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62649147/16360266):

- Open Page Designer for your page with the Interactive Grid
- In the left side menu "Render Tree" should open
- There, right click on your Interative Grid component and click "Create Dynamic Action"
- In the right side menu in "When" - "Event" select "Save [Interactive Grid]"
- In the left side menu select the item under "True" branch of your dynamic action (this item should be red so must be easy to find)
- In the right side menu in "Affected Elements" - "Selection Type" choose "Region", in "Affected Elements" - "Region" select your Interactiove Grid, in "Identification" - "Action" select either "Refresh" (this will only refresh the Interactive Grid -- for me it kinda works, but gives a JavaScript error and some warnings) or "Submit Page" (this will reload the whole page)

Alternatively, and maybe it is "the right way", you can replace this "Automatic Row Processing" with your own proccess, but you'll have to write your own PL/SQL code to do row modifications. I think, that's what was proposed in the question comments.